# Problems compiling nodes using pcl in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: pcl, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an issue with compiling ROS nodes that use pcl on Ubuntu 11.10.  When I try to compile my node on 10.04 I don't have any problems. Both installations were installed from the debian packages ros-electric-desktop-full and ros-electric-perception-pcl-addons.

1. Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit, ROS Electric: **Works**
2. Ubuntu 11.10, 32-bit, ROS Electric: **Doesn't compile**

My node is pretty simple, mainly just visualizing a static point cloud that I create.

In the second case, I get the following compiler error during linking.

```
...
Linking CXX executable ../bin/publish_primitives
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/publish_primitives.dir/src/publish_primitives.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(vtkObjectBase*)'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(vtkObjectBase*)' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libvtkCommon.so.5.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libvtkCommon.so.5.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

I manually added the required libraries in CMakeLists.txt (below) and it fixes the compiler problem.

```
rosbuild_add_executable(publish_primitives src/publish_primitives.cpp)
target_link_libraries(publish_primitives libvtkCommon.so libvtkFiltering.so )
```

Messing with the compiler flags for pcl is beyond me, so I'll leave it to the higher ups to figure out what is going on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12817/problems-compiling-nodes-using-pcl-in-ubuntu-11.10/) by [Kyle Strabala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1173/kyle-strabala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like there was a change in linker behavior. [thread with links](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-March/133601.html)

[Fedora documentation of the change](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChangeInImplicitDSOLinking)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After upgrading either ROS or Ubuntu from an earlier distribution, you should clean your working trees and rebuild them. Three different ways to do that:

- `rosmake --pre-clean`
- `make clean` in every package
- check out new copies and build everything from scratch

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kyle Strabala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1173/kyle-strabala/) on 2012-02-07**:
I meant that I am using a fresh install of everything (Ubuntu 11.10, ROS Electric from deb packages).  I have tried cleaning and re-building without success.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-01**:
What does that mean? Can't you rebuild your working copies?

**Comment by [Kyle Strabala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1173/kyle-strabala/) on 2012-02-01**:
Unfortunately, my 11.10 system was built from scratch.  Also, I had three other 11.10 users try it on their systems with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this can help you but I had almost the identical problem and I solved adding `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` in `target_link_libraries`, like

```
target_link_libraries(publish_primitives ${PCL_LIBRARIES} libvtkCommon.so libvtkFiltering.so )
```

---

Originally posted by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) with karma: 197 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-31**:
The `PCL_LIBRARIES` link should not be necessary if you are in ROS and you correctly specified the dependencies in your package manifest (as described in the ROS PCL tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials ).

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-31**:
Furthermore, if you want to include all VTK libraries, you can use `find_package(VTK REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(example ${VTK_LIBRARIES})`.